# How to use dpkg to upgrade - (Y/I/N/O/D/Z) [default=N] ? Y

Tags: chef-infra

I am tryijng

How do I handle this situation with chef upgrade of a dpkg?

```
dpkg_package "#{Chef::Config[:file_cache_path]}/elasticsearch-#{version}.deb" do
  action :install
end

==> Modified (by you or by a script) since installation.  ==> Package  
distributor has shipped an updated version.    What would you like to   
do about it ?  Your options are:  
Y or I  : install the package maintainer's version  
N or O  : keep your currently-installed version  
D     : show the differences between the versions  
Z     : start a shell to examine the sit
```

I want the default to be N

Comment: What changes have been made on this installation? Do you want to not upgrade a package if its already there?

Comment: this is a chef question.  easy to do in bash

Comment: I did ask you for chef only and I am not doubting whether you can do it in bash or not. There can be multiple ways to do it given what you intend to do.

Comment: again you can do in bash echo Y | dpgk -i I want do with dpgk resource

Answer (score 1):

In general this shouldn't happen, we run all the install commands under `$DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive`. If you're seeing this from Chef it probably means something had gone Very Very Wrong™.

Comment: it happened when I try to upgrade the elasticsearch deb file and there are already e.g. /etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml files.  A fresh install works  fine

Comment: Sounds like a bug in Chef, can you please file a GitHub issue?